# Сохранение текстового файла с названием из первой строки

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

При нажатии кнопки сохранения текста написанного в `RichTextBox`, отображается `OpenFileDialog`. Первые пять слов из первой строчки в `RichTextBox` должны быть названием файла при сохранении. Как это сделать?

```
        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog svf = new SaveFileDialog();
        svf.Filter = "Text Files (.rtf)|*.rtf";
        svf.Title = "Save";
        if (svf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(svf.FileName);
            sw.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog svf = new SaveFileDialog();
    var firstLine = richTextBox1.Lines.FirstOrDefault();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstLine))
    {
        svf.FileName = String.Join(" ", firstLine.Split(' ').Take(5));
    }
    ...
}
```

Почитать:

- [`TextBoxBase.Lines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`FileDialog.FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Enumerable.Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Захватывает аж несколько предложений. Можно как-то ограничить название примерно до 5 слов?

Comment: @Kaya можно. Обновите вопрос.

Comment: @Kaya обновлено.